# djangocms - cannot import name 'NamespaceAlreadyRegistered'

Tags: python, django, pip, python-3.6, django-cms

I have developed a simple project with DjangoCMS(3.7.2) and it works great in the local. I 'm gonna run it on a ubuntu server, which I have another Django project run on it with no issues. Both of my projects are built using python 3.6 & MySQL database. I took these steps to run my new project:

1. Cloned the project from the server via git and updated the `settings.py` file
2. Created an empty database on the server
3. Installed a virtualenv on server by `python3 -m venv venv`
4. Activated the `venv`  and upgraded `pip`
5. Installed requirements successfully using `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. Tried to Migrate by `python3 manage.py migrate`

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 31, in <module>
    from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
  File "/var/www/pishbiny/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py", line 18, in <module>
    from menus.exceptions import NamespaceAlreadyRegistered
ImportError: cannot import name 'NamespaceAlreadyRegistered'
```

- Following dependencies are installed on the server:

```
asgiref                    3.2.7
chardet                    3.0.4
cms                        0.0.2
dj-database-url            0.5.0
Django                     3.0.5
django-classy-tags         1.0.0
django-cms                 3.7.2
django-filer               1.7.0
django-formtools           2.2
django-js-asset            1.2.2
django-mptt                0.11.0
django-polymorphic         2.1.2
django-sekizai             1.1.0
django-treebeard           4.3.1
djangocms-admin-style      1.5.0
djangocms-attributes-field 1.2.0
djangocms-bootstrap4       1.6.0
djangocms-file             2.4.0
djangocms-googlemap        1.4.0
djangocms-icon             1.5.0
djangocms-installer        1.2.3
djangocms-link             2.6.0
djangocms-picture          2.4.0
djangocms-snippet          2.3.0
djangocms-style            2.3.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor    3.9.0
djangocms-video            2.3.0
dsdev-utils                1.0.4
easy-thumbnails            2.7
html5lib                   1.0.1
Menus                      0.2.0
mysqlclient                1.4.6
Pillow                     7.1.2
pip                        20.1
pkg-resources              0.0.0
pytz                       2020.1
setuptools                 39.0.1
six                        1.14.0
sqlparse                   0.3.1
tzlocal                    2.0.0
Unidecode                  1.1.1
webencodings               0.5.1
wheel                      0.34.2
```

I removed the venv and reinstalled all the dependencies several times, but it didn't work.
Let me know what is my mistake. Many thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: [`menus`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/tree/develop/menus) from django-cms seems to be clashing with `Menus` and `django-menus` in your requirements. I would try removing them from your requirements, then creating a new virtual env.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried this too, but still, I get the same error.

Comment: @Alasdair in the case of removing `Menus` I got another error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menus.exceptions'
`

Comment: I created an empty virtual env, ran `python -m pip install "django-cms==3.72"`. I then opened a Python shell, and the line `from menus.exceptions import NamespaceAlreadyRegistered` worked for me. If it's not `Menus` or `django-menus` that is causing the problem, I guess it's something else in your requirements.

Comment: Yes, surprisingly, by reinstalling Django-cms one more time, it worked. So weird! thank you @Alasdair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) mentioned:

I reinstalled the Django-CMS module by running `python3 -m pip install "django-cms==3.7.2"`, and surprisingly it worked.